# List<object> to JSONArray

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, list

i need to create a JSONARRAY from a List of objects to send for my webService then get this JSONArray with javaScript and create the objects again.

observation: those objects are in JSON file.

```
public static List<Funcionario> pegaFuncionario() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("arquivos/usuarios"));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(mapper.readValue(line, Funcionario.class));
    }
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return list;

}
```

Comment: Try Jackson JSON library.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: i dont know how make function to turn this return in a JSONArray

Comment: Do you want a JSONArray java object, or a String?

Comment: Your return type is not `JSONArray`

Comment: i need to send all this list of objects at once to webService,so its just possible with a JSONArray, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume because you need to send this to a web service over HTTP that you require a JSON Array String. Jackson can write objects to JSON Strings and will treat `List` as a `JSONArray`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Funcionario> list = pegaFuncionario();
String jsonArray = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
```